# Search text in an oracle database for characters like 'a' to match the following characters: 'a', 'à', 'â' and 'ä'

Tags: oracle, search, internationalization

I have an Oracle database with data in French language.

My users mentionned that they would like to be able to find data, regardless of accents on characters, so words like:

- **École** could be found by typing **Ecole** or **École**
- **Père-Noël** could be found by typing **Pere-Noel** or **Père-Noel** or **Père-Noël**

Since this is a search that will be made on many columns and on tables with many rows, that there are many characters which can have accents in French, I would like to have an efficient way to match accentuated characters with unnaccentuated version.

Does Oracle provide any facility for this and if not, what solutions are available to do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation for Oracle fulltext indices (Oracle Text) - essentially, you'll want to create your own lexer for this.

To create a simple fulltext index:

```
create index fulltext_idx on tab(col) indextype is ctxsys.context;
```

UPDATE: Using the auto_lexer might also be an option (since it supports French), see
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cdatadic.htm#BHCGJHDH

Comment: Would this work on multiple-columns ? In my query, I am doing something like: SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE upper(FirstName || ';' || LastName || ';' || Adress) LIKE '%ERIC%';

Comment: You can combine several columns (even several tables) into a single fulltext index, using a user data store - see e.g. http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9455353124561