# Matching company names in two tables

Tags: sql, string, oracle, duplicates

I have two tables with company names and their ids, the table `Corporation_Name` has `ID` and `NAME`, the other table `DATA_Excel` has `CORPORATION as ID and C_Name as name`; I have to match company names in the data table with `Corporation Name` to make sure all the companies exist if not i only have to insert the company which is not present in Corporation name.

Currently i am using this query:

```
Select Distinct (B.corporation), B.C_name
from data_excel B, corporation_name A
where B.C_name <> A.name
```

also some times this is the case:

```
87  Société Générale de Belgique
87  Societe Generale de Belgique
```

Comment: Look up nlssort or 'Oracle Text' for ways of matching accented characters. E.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144605/search-text-in-an-oracle-database-for-characters-like-a-to-match-the-following)

Comment: Is the query OK? for finding names existing in Data_Excel but are not present in Corporation_Name

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. It always operates on *all* columns of your select statement. The parentheses around the column name have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not finding what you are looking for. You are all companies from A and matching them with all companies in B, meaning it will return a record for Societe Generale <> Fortis

Start with this:

```
    SELECT B.Corporation, B.C_Name
      FROM data_excel B
LEFT OUTER JOIN corporation_name A
        ON B.C_Name = A.Name
     WHERE A.Name IS NULL
```

This will still not solve everything, you will still have to replace

```
        ON B.C_Name = A.Name
```

With something like what John Doyle suggested, because Société will still not match Societe!

Comment: but this query will return all the Company names that are in Data_Excel but not in Corporation Name with exception of Société will not match Societe?

Comment: Yes. The 'OUTER JOIN' wil try to match all records in your Excel with matching records in your database. A normal JOIN woul dleave out records that do not match, but a LEFT OUTER JOIN will inlcude those records where you have a match in your Excel but not in your database. The database-side will then be null, and those are the records you are interested in.

Comment: Now if i want to check these values e.g C_name in data base if there are similar names that exist in database how can i do that?

Comment: I suggest you look at the link John Doyle provided, or open a seperate question for that. The interpretation of "similar"  is quite database-dependant :)